# How to make a react-native App as a server and others as a client

Tags: reactjs, react-native

here's the scenario for my question,
i'm making a check-in application for organizers to check in their attendees usually they dont have access to a good network connection so they cant connect to server to update data.

now i want to make 1 of devices a server and others will connect to that and make request to that device. can anyone help me with this ? :)

Comment: If they don't have access to a network connection how will they receive the updates?

Comment: they update once and its over :)

Comment: Ofc its not the best solution if you have better solutions tell me :)